# https and http working on local network but only http working outside local network

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

I'm developing a website. Once when I had Windows 10 + XAMPP + Cloudflare-flexible-ssl I could access my website from outside local network with the lock icon appearing in the browsers and https working like a charm (dispite this solution not being secure between my home-server and cloudflare's end). Now I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 + NGINX + self-made ssl certificate with certbot. It is working like a charm from local network but when I try to access my domain from outside my local network I end up with HTTP working fine but HTTPS stuck with ERR_CONNECTION_TIME_OUT or ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, mostly after an page loading that takes very long and never ends.

```
sudo netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46285         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33060         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

```
nmap -sT mydomain.com

Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-08-31 19:03 -03
Nmap scan report for mydomain.com (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00014s latency).
rDNS record for 127.0.0.1: localhost
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
3306/tcp open  mysql
```

```
nmap -sT my.ipv4.public.ip(192.XX.XXX.XXX)

Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-08-31 19:11 -03
Nmap scan report for 191-055-235-169.xd-dynamic.algartelecom.com.br (my.ipv4.public.ip)
Host is up (0.0018s latency).
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https
```

```
sudo iptables -L -vn

Chain INPUT (policy DROP 153 packets, 25075 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 5282  638K f2b-sshd   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22
50363 4662K ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
50363 4662K ufw-before-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
14107 1158K ufw-after-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  153 25075 ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  153 25075 ufw-reject-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  153 25075 ufw-track-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-before-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-after-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-reject-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-track-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 7 packets, 316 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
24573   61M ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
24573   61M ufw-before-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 2315  144K ufw-after-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 2315  144K ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 2315  144K ufw-reject-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 2315  144K ufw-track-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain f2b-sshd (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   31  1804 REJECT     all  --  *      *       151.63.97.42         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   20  1648 REJECT     all  --  *      *       70.51.16.212         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
  211 18552 REJECT     all  --  *      *       110.42.190.60        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
 5020  616K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   70  5460 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:137
   42  9213 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:138
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:139
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:445
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
13842 1119K ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  146 20965 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
    0     0 ufw-user-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
10280 1340K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
24083 2022K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:67 dpt:68
16000 1300K ufw-not-local  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 1836  138K ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251          udp dpt:5353
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
14164 1162K ufw-user-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
10282 1340K ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
11976   60M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 2315  144K ufw-user-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  210 28471 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
 1836  138K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
13954 1133K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
    0     0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
13954 1133K DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 2112  127K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
  196 16547 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   45  2732 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    9   492 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
    3   172 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:1701
    0     0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:1701
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443 /* 'dapp_Nginx%20Full' */

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/mydomain.com.conf

map $http_origin $allow_origin {
    ~^https?://(.*\.)?lojascolmeia.com.br(:\d+)?$ $http_origin;
    ~^https?://(.*\.)?localhost(:\d+)?$ $http_origin;
    default "";
}

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}
upstream wsbackend {
    server localhost:2020;
}

server {
    # gzip Settings
    #should add!!!: gzip_static on;
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    
    # cache-control
    # Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|mp3|ogg|ogv|webm|htc|woff2|woff|webp|webm|ttf|)$ {
        expires 1M;
        access_log off;
        # max-age must be in seconds
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=8380800, public";
    }
    # CSS and Javascript
    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
        expires 1y;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=8380800, public";
    }

    server_name _ mydomain.com;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    index   index.php;
    root    /var/www/html/mydomain;
    access_log /var/www/html/logs/nginx_access.log;
    error_log /var/www/html/logs/nginx_error.log;

    # HEADERS
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $allow_origin;
    # content-security-policy
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff always;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always; 

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?goto=$uri&$args;
    }

client_max_body_size 100M;

        location ~ \.php$ {                 
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        }

        location /dbadm {
                auth_basic "Admin Login";
                auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pma_pass;
        }

#   location ~ \.json {
#       add_header Content-Type application/json;
#    }

    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot  
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/lojascolmeia.com.br/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/lojascolmeia.com.br/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

#proxy_ssl_server_name on;

location /websocket {
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8443;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
proxy_send_timeout 86400s;
keepalive_timeout 86400s;
# prevents 502 bad gateway error
proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
proxy_buffers 8 32k;
proxy_buffer_size 64k;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}

}
server {
    if ($host = mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name _ mydomain.com;
    listen      80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    server_tokens off;      #https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/hide-nginx-server-version-header/
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

**tcpdump and then loading my webpage from localnetwork**

```
sudo tcpdump -n -i any src or dst 192.XX.XXX.XXX(home-network-ipv4-public-ip-from-another-device-from-local-network-connected-to-my-server-via-ssh)

tcpdump: data link type LINUX_SLL2
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL2 (Linux cooked v2), snapshot length 262144 bytes
19:35:39.086944 enp2s0 In  IP 191.55.235.169.54086 > 192.168.1.107.443: Flags [S], seq 3186999685, win 64240, options [mss 1412,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
19:35:39.087013 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [S.], seq 2236039596, ack 3186999686, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
19:35:39.091325 enp2s0 In  IP 191.55.235.169.54086 > 192.168.1.107.443: Flags [.], ack 1, win 512, length 0
19:35:39.091377 enp2s0 In  IP 191.55.235.169.54086 > 192.168.1.107.443: Flags [P.], seq 1:518, ack 1, win 512, length 517
19:35:39.091399 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [.], ack 518, win 501, length 0
19:35:39.092254 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [.], seq 1:1413, ack 518, win 501, length 1412
19:35:39.092256 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [.], seq 1413:2825, ack 518, win 501, length 1412
19:35:39.092257 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [P.], seq 2825:4097, ack 518, win 501, length 1272
19:35:39.093381 enp2s0 In  IP 191.55.235.169.54086 > 192.168.1.107.443: Flags [.], ack 2825, win 512, length 0
19:35:39.094964 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [P.], seq 4097:4580, ack 518, win 501, length 483
19:35:39.096049 enp2s0 In  IP 191.55.235.169.54086 > 192.168.1.107.443: Flags [.], ack 4580, win 512, length 0
19:35:39.102807 enp2s0 In  IP 191.55.235.169.54086 > 192.168.1.107.443: Flags [P.], seq 518:582, ack 4580, win 512, length 64
19:35:39.102834 enp2s0 In  IP 191.55.235.169.54086 > 192.168.1.107.443: Flags [P.], seq 582:674, ack 4580, win 512, length 92
19:35:39.102887 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [.], ack 674, win 501, length 0
19:35:39.103058 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [P.], seq 4580:4659, ack 674, win 501, length 79
19:35:39.103137 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [P.], seq 4659:4738, ack 674, win 501, length 79
19:35:39.103205 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [P.], seq 4738:4809, ack 674, win 501, length 71
19:35:39.103301 enp2s0 In  IP 191.55.235.169.54086 > 192.168.1.107.443: Flags [P.], seq 674:1365, ack 4580, win 512, length 691
19:35:39.104771 enp2s0 In  IP 191.55.235.169.54086 > 192.168.1.107.443: Flags [.], ack 4809, win 512, length 0
19:35:39.104793 enp2s0 In  IP 191.55.235.169.54086 > 192.168.1.107.443: Flags [P.], seq 1365:1396, ack 4809, win 512, length 31
19:35:39.104812 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [.], ack 1396, win 501, length 0
19:35:39.115063 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [.], seq 4809:6221, ack 1396, win 501, length 1412
19:35:39.115066 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [.], seq 6221:7633, ack 1396, win 501, length 1412
19:35:39.115068 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [.], seq 7633:9045, ack 1396, win 501, length 1412
19:35:39.115069 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [.], seq 9045:10457, ack 1396, win 501, length 1412
19:35:39.115070 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [P.], seq 10457:11869, ack 1396, win 501, length 1412
19:35:39.115268 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [.], seq 11869:13281, ack 1396, win 501, length 1412
19:35:39.115384 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [.], seq 13281:14693, ack 1396, win 501, length 1412
19:35:39.115511 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [.], seq 14693:16105, ack 1396, win 501, length 1412
19:35:39.115630 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [.], seq 16105:17517, ack 1396, win 501, length 1412
19:35:39.115749 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [P.], seq 17517:18929, ack 1396, win 501, length 1412
19:35:39.116796 enp2s0 In  IP 191.55.235.169.54086 > 192.168.1.107.443: Flags [.], ack 7633, win 512, length 0
19:35:39.116831 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [.], seq 18929:20341, ack 1396, win 501, length 1412
19:35:39.116833 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [.], seq 20341:21753, ack 1396, win 501, length 1412
19:35:39.116834 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [P.], seq 21753:22031, ack 1396, win 501, length 278
19:35:39.117833 enp2s0 In  IP 191.55.235.169.54086 > 192.168.1.107.443: Flags [.], ack 17517, win 512, length 0
19:35:39.118256 enp2s0 In  IP 191.55.235.169.54086 > 192.168.1.107.443: Flags [.], ack 22031, win 512, length 0
19:35:39.391422 enp2s0 In  IP 191.55.235.169.54086 > 192.168.1.107.443: Flags [P.], seq 1396:1615, ack 22031, win 512, length 219
19:35:39.391510 enp2s0 In  IP 191.55.235.169.54086 > 192.168.1.107.443: Flags [P.], seq 1615:2081, ack 22031, win 512, length 466
19:35:39.391551 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [.], ack 2081, win 501, length 0
19:35:39.391761 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [P.], seq 22031:22066, ack 2081, win 501, length 35
19:35:39.394267 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [P.], seq 22066:22417, ack 2081, win 501, length 351
19:35:39.395852 enp2s0 In  IP 191.55.235.169.54086 > 192.168.1.107.443: Flags [.], ack 22417, win 511, length 0
19:35:39.402034 enp2s0 In  IP 191.55.235.169.54086 > 192.168.1.107.443: Flags [P.], seq 2081:2207, ack 22417, win 511, length 126
19:35:39.402071 enp2s0 In  IP 191.55.235.169.54086 > 192.168.1.107.443: Flags [P.], seq 2207:2537, ack 22417, win 511, length 330
19:35:39.402121 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [.], ack 2537, win 501, length 0
19:35:39.402303 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [P.], seq 22417:22452, ack 2537, win 501, length 35
19:35:39.404553 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.443 > 191.55.235.169.54086: Flags [P.], seq 22452:22791, ack 2537, win 501, length 339
^C
49 packets captured
49 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

**tcpdump and then loading my webpage from device outside local network (over 3G)

```
sudo tcpdump -n -i any src or dst XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX(my-phone-ip-over-3G)

tcpdump: data link type LINUX_SLL2
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL2 (Linux cooked v2), snapshot length 262144 bytes
19:59:56.882577 enp2s0 In  IP 200.160.124.42.37474 > 192.168.1.107.80: Flags [SEW], seq 1941385008, win 65535, options [mss 1412,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 1626285022 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
19:59:56.882642 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.80 > 200.160.124.42.37474: Flags [S.E], seq 971375185, ack 1941385009, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1104199128 ecr 1626285022,nop,wscale 7], length 0
19:59:56.905511 enp2s0 In  IP 200.160.124.42.37474 > 192.168.1.107.80: Flags [.], ack 1, win 4112, options [nop,nop,TS val 1626285045 ecr 1104199128], length 0
19:59:56.935141 enp2s0 In  IP 200.160.124.42.37474 > 192.168.1.107.80: Flags [P.], seq 1:403, ack 1, win 4112, options [nop,nop,TS val 1626285076 ecr 1104199128], length 402: HTTP: GET / HTTP/1.1
19:59:56.935175 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.80 > 200.160.124.42.37474: Flags [.], ack 403, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 1104199180 ecr 1626285076], length 0
19:59:56.935289 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.80 > 200.160.124.42.37474: Flags [P.], seq 1:359, ack 403, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 1104199180 ecr 1626285076], length 358: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
19:59:56.966260 enp2s0 In  IP 200.160.124.42.37474 > 192.168.1.107.80: Flags [.], ack 359, win 4101, options [nop,nop,TS val 1626285105 ecr 1104199180], length 0
19:59:57.087070 enp2s0 In  IP 200.160.124.42.37474 > 192.168.1.107.80: Flags [.], ack 359, win 4101, length 0
19:59:57.087096 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.1.107.80 > 200.160.124.42.37474: Flags [.], ack 403, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 1104199332 ecr 1626285105], length 0
20:00:05.684479 enp2s0 In  IP 200.160.124.42.37474 > 192.168.1.107.80: Flags [R], seq 1941385411, win 0, length 0
10 packets captured
10 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

**MY MODEM(NOKIA G-240W-G) CONFIG FOR PORT FOWARDING**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PO8I.png)

What I have done:

1. Tryed disabling UFW (Ubuntu firewall) but still not working outside local network.
2. Called my ISP over 10 times. They always say it must be a local network problem. They swear all ports are opened and free to use it.

I'm thinking to fall back to Cloudflare`s flexible ssl and work all trafic upon port 80 or pay for premium internet access or something...

Comment: It is unclear from where you made your nmap, but judging from the tcpdump it is likely from inside the network. The tcpdump shows clearly that port 443 from outside does not treach your machine. Note that port 443 might be used internally by your modem to access management from outside and thus will not work with port forwarding - see also https://www.reddit.com/r/hyperoptic/comments/ovivl4/port_443_has_stopped_working_recently/

Comment: You are totally right! Sorry about that!
So your link is saying I should try change my Nokia-modem-router-wifi that was given me from 
 my ISP to a bridge mode and try to 443 port foward from the new Router I just connected to the Nokia-modem(bridge mode now) and checks if the problem was something to do with the NAT or something the old Nokia-modem-router-wifi was doing with 443 port and bypassing my order to foward 443 to my server... That will cost a  little, but I must give a try!

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded my app to an remote VPS exactly the way it was setted on my local network and everything just worked fine. So the problem was my ISP blocking the ports...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).